# Error Reading HTML table on Power Automate

Tags: html, xml, power-automate

The basis of my task is to find a way to auto update a OneDrive excel file when a specific mail pattern arrives in my inbox. Found and followed along a tutorial that I found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88.
But along the way I found that I was getting the following error on using Xpath with xml to extract the HTML table as a JSON object:
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'ComposeHTML' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 1, position 14298.

From the defined error, the problem seems to be that &nbsp isn't one of XMLs predefined entities.
The problem with this is I am reading HTML input dynamically from mail and cannot predefine the input.
Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: XML and HTML are different.  Sometimes that can be read with same tool, but often will fail.  You are trying to read html with an xml tool and it will not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your &nbsp is missing ;

You should replace &nbsp with `&nbsp;`